# Error R14 and H12, worker timeout deploying with heroku

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

Just lost at sea trying to deploy my app with heroku. The app runs very well locally, at most a couple seconds to load any given request. I set up a git repo and virtualenv according to the dash deployment page specifications. I ran the same process to deploy the example app through another repo earlier, but my own app has large csv files in addition to the main app file. Here's a list of files in the repo I'm trying to deploy, along with the file sizes:

```
.gitignore                         idk, very small
Procfile                           31 bytes
VOO_data_6y_wMA_365.csv            247 KB
jensen_app.py                      18 KB
requirements.txt                   584 bytes
return_free_rates.csv              118 KB
sp500_final_6y_wMA_365.csv         169.9 MB
```

The last one is big I suppose, but again locally the app runs very quick.

I set up an empty repo, set up the virtual environment, install the necessary app packages from the requirements.txt file into the virtualenv, add all these files to the repo and commit, create the app, push the repo to heroku master. All this done according to this page https://dash.plotly.com/deployment

As I said, I did this with the example app already, no issues, but the example app is small, and there are no additional csv files that the example app has to call. My own app page will not even load on heroku, I just get an application error. Going through the tails I get a few notable errors:

```
2021-01-01T20:14:36.267269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=576M(112.7%)
2021-01-01T20:14:36.269624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

over and over again. I tried upgrading to a hobby Dyno but this did not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it was upgrading my Dyno or changing my web concurrence to 2 from 3, but the app works now.